# Sub Userform calendar populating on spreadsheet cell instead of on userform

Tags: excel, calendar, vba

I have run across the problem of using DTpicker for dates.  So I have added my own calendar popup and now when I am in the usereform and click on the box or button for the calendar it populates the date on the original spreadsheet (it looks like in the last selected cell) instead of into my userform - TextBox8.  I am at a loss, Sometimes it works like I intended and other times it doesn't and does the previous.

```
Private Sub Date_Button_1_Click()
UserForm1.TextBox8 = ActiveCell
'this is the first calendar button & box
frmCalendar.Show_Cal
UserForm1.TextBox8.Value = g_sDate
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox8_Enter()
UserForm1.TextBox8 = ActiveCell
g_bForm = True
frmCalendar.Show_Cal
UserForm1.TextBox8.Value = g_sDate
End Sub
```

I am sure it is staring me in the face.  Any assistance would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure do you have linked cells? to the textbox